# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token (at react.js?v=4ace817c:1:1)

Tags: reactjs, syntax-error, vite, unexpected-token, radix-ui

Im building an app using react in vite with shadcn UI library and so

```
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import * as z from "zod";
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";

import "./App.css";
import "./no-scroll.css";

import sideImg from "./assets/01.png";

import Link from "next/link";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import { ThemeProvider } from "./components/theme-provider";
import {
  Drawer,
  DrawerClose,
  DrawerContent,
  DrawerDescription,
  DrawerFooter,
  DrawerHeader,
  DrawerTitle,
  DrawerTrigger,
} from "./components/ui/drawer";
import {
  Form,
  FormControl,
  FormDescription,
  FormField,
  FormItem,
  FormLabel,
  FormMessage,
} from "@/components/ui/form";
import {
  AlertDialog,
  AlertDialogAction,
  AlertDialogCancel,
  AlertDialogContent,
  AlertDialogDescription,
  AlertDialogFooter,
  AlertDialogHeader,
  AlertDialogTitle,
} from "@/components/ui/alert-dialog";
import { Input } from "./components/ui/input";
import { cn } from "./lib/utils";
import { useState } from "react";

const formSchema = z.object({
  username: z.string().min(2, {
    message: "Username must be at least 2 characters.",
  }),
  pwd: z.string().min(4, {
    message: "Password Should Be At least 4 Characters.",
  }),
});

export default function Home() {
  try {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [openFailed, setOpenFailed] = useState(false);
  const [openLogged, setOpenLogged] = useState(false);

  const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof formSchema>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      username: "",
      pwd: "",
    },
  });

  function onSubmit(values: z.infer<typeof formSchema>) {
    window.alert(JSON.stringify(values));
    setOpen(true);
  }

  return (
    <ThemeProvider defaultTheme="system" storageKey="vite-ui-theme">
      <h1 className="title">Welcome To TeaDB</h1>
      <p className="para">An Easy Way To Manage Tea Data</p>
      <img src={sideImg} className="sideImg img" />
      <Drawer>
        <DrawerTrigger asChild>
          <Button>Get Started</Button>
        </DrawerTrigger>
        <DrawerContent>
          <div className="mx-auto w-full max-w-sm">
            <DrawerHeader>
              <DrawerTitle>Log In</DrawerTitle>
              <DrawerDescription>
                Log In With The Credintials From The Admin
              </DrawerDescription>
            </DrawerHeader>

            <Form {...form}>
              <form
                onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
                className="space-y-8"
              >
                <FormField
                  control={form.control}
                  name="username"
                  render={({ field }) => (
                    <FormItem>
                      <FormLabel>Username</FormLabel>
                      <FormControl>
                        <Input placeholder="Username" {...field} />
                      </FormControl>
                      <FormMessage />
                      <div className="space-reducer"></div>
                    </FormItem>
                  )}
                />
                <FormField
                  control={form.control}
                  name="pwd"
                  render={({ field }) => (
                    <FormItem>
                      <FormLabel>Password</FormLabel>
                      <FormControl>
                        <Input placeholder="Password" {...field} />
                      </FormControl>
                      <FormDescription>Enter The Password</FormDescription>
                      <FormMessage />
                    </FormItem>
                  )}
                />
              </form>
            </Form>

            <DrawerFooter>
              <Button onClick={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>Continue</Button>
              <DrawerClose asChild>
                <Button variant="outline">Cancel</Button>
              </DrawerClose>
            </DrawerFooter>
          </div>
        </DrawerContent>
      </Drawer>
      <AlertDialog open={open} onOpenChange={setOpen}>
        <AlertDialogContent>
          <AlertDialogHeader>
            <AlertDialogTitle>Loging In...</AlertDialogTitle>
            <AlertDialogDescription>
              Please wait we are currently verifying your credintials
            </AlertDialogDescription>
          </AlertDialogHeader>
          <svg
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            width="72"
            height="72"
            viewBox="0 0 24 24"
            fill="none"
            stroke="currentColor"
            strokeWidth="2"
            strokeLinecap="round"
            strokeLinejoin="round"
            className={cn("animate-loader")}
          >
            <path d="M21 12a9 9 0 1 1-6.219-8.56" />
          </svg>
        </AlertDialogContent>
      </AlertDialog>

      <AlertDialog open={openFailed} onOpenChange={setOpenFailed}>
        <AlertDialogContent>
          <AlertDialogHeader>
            <AlertDialogTitle>Failed To Log In</AlertDialogTitle>
            <AlertDialogDescription>
              The entered username or password is incorrect
            </AlertDialogDescription>
          </AlertDialogHeader>
          <AlertDialogFooter>
            <AlertDialogCancel>Okay</AlertDialogCancel>
          </AlertDialogFooter>
        </AlertDialogContent>
      </AlertDialog>

      <AlertDialog open={openLogged} onOpenChange={setOpenLogged}>
        <AlertDialogContent>
          <AlertDialogHeader>
            <AlertDialogTitle>Succsefully Logged In</AlertDialogTitle>
            <AlertDialogDescription>
              Click continue to go the dashboard
            </AlertDialogDescription>
          </AlertDialogHeader>
          <AlertDialogFooter>
            <AlertDialogAction asChild>
              <Link href="https://google.com">Continue</Link>
            </AlertDialogAction>
          </AlertDialogFooter>
        </AlertDialogContent>
      </AlertDialog>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`sss : ${err}`);
  }
}
```

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token (at react.js?v=4ace817c:1:1)`

I tried EVERY possible think i know and i could do and it wont go away.

the page wont load. i mean the the page's tab's title and icon loads but not other

i also tried checking for any mistaken errors like for extra {} and mis used imports

it's like my react page dosent load however i commented some Imports and the relative components of those and it loaded after commenting these:

```
// import {
//   AlertDialog,
//   AlertDialogAction,
//   AlertDialogCancel,
//   AlertDialogContent,
//   AlertDialogDescription,
//   AlertDialogFooter,
//   AlertDialogHeader,
//   AlertDialogTitle,
// } from "@/components/ui/alert-dialog";
```

```
// import { cn } from "./lib/utils";
```

```
// import Link from "next/link";
```

and also these

````
      {/* <AlertDialog open={open} onOpenChange={setOpen}>
        <AlertDialogContent>
          <AlertDialogHeader>
            <AlertDialogTitle>Loging In...</AlertDialogTitle>
            <AlertDialogDescription>
              Please wait we are currently verifying your credintials
            </AlertDialogDescription>
          </AlertDialogHeader>
          <svg
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            width="72"
            height="72"
            viewBox="0 0 24 24"
            fill="none"
            stroke="currentColor"
            strokeWidth="2"
            strokeLinecap="round"
            strokeLinejoin="round"
            className={cn("animate-loader")}
          >
            <path d="M21 12a9 9 0 1 1-6.219-8.56" />
          </svg>
        </AlertDialogContent>
      </AlertDialog>

      <AlertDialog open={openFailed} onOpenChange={setOpenFailed}>
        <AlertDialogContent>
          <AlertDialogHeader>
            <AlertDialogTitle>Failed To Log In</AlertDialogTitle>
            <AlertDialogDescription>
              The entered username or password is incorrect
            </AlertDialogDescription>
          </AlertDialogHeader>
          <AlertDialogFooter>
            <AlertDialogCancel>Okay</AlertDialogCancel>
          </AlertDialogFooter>
        </AlertDialogContent>
      </AlertDialog>

      <AlertDialog open={openLogged} onOpenChange={setOpenLogged}>
        <AlertDialogContent>
          <AlertDialogHeader>
            <AlertDialogTitle>Succsefully Logged In</AlertDialogTitle>
            <AlertDialogDescription>
              Click continue to go the dashboard
            </AlertDialogDescription>
          </AlertDialogHeader>
          <AlertDialogFooter>
            <AlertDialogAction asChild>
              <Link href="https://google.com">Continue</Link>
            </AlertDialogAction>
          </AlertDialogFooter>
        </AlertDialogContent>
      </AlertDialog> */}
    ```
````

Comment: You cannot wrap the entire component in a try-catch like you have. Ideally, even before the token error, you should see your build failing because of this syntax.
Change error handling first to see if the issue persists.

Comment: hmm ok i'll see

Comment: it's like my react page dosent load but now i commented some Imports and the relative components of those and it loaded after commenting these:

`// import {
//   AlertDialog,
//   AlertDialogAction,
//   AlertDialogCancel,
//   AlertDialogContent,
//   AlertDialogDescription,
//   AlertDialogFooter,
//   AlertDialogHeader,
//   AlertDialogTitle,
// } from "@/components/ui/alert-dialog";`

`// import { cn } from "./lib/utils";`

`// import Link from "next/link";`

also the alertdialog thingies in the bottom

Comment: after some analyzing i found that this guy is causing the problem
`{/* <Link href="https://google.com">Continue</Link> */}`

idk whats wrong with since im new to react

Comment: Don't post commented out code. And also you can't post code blocks in comments. If you want to provide additional context you should edit the question.

Comment: @SethnunThunder, make sure the Link component is imported from the correct library.